# Is possible that find numbers where the product of 3 numbers is congruent modulo to 1?

Tags: rsa

It is possible that find the $a, b, c$ randomly in here?
$$
abc \equiv 1{\pmod {\varphi (N)}}
$$

Instead of
$$
de \equiv 1{\pmod {\varphi (N)}}
$$

in the RSA Algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

> It is possible that find the a, b, c randomly in here?  $abc \equiv 1{\pmod {\varphi (N)}} $

The most obvious way is to select $a, b$ randomly (relatively prime to $\phi(N)$), and then compute $c = (ab)^{-1} \bmod{ \phi(N) }$.  It is easy to show that if $a, b$ are chosen uniformly and independently from $\mathbb{Z}_{N}^*$, then $c$ is also chosen uniformly.